# How to override template "folder_full_view_item.pt" only for a Custom Type?

Tags: templates, plone, overriding, theming

This question has evolved in a confusing way. Some of its parts though, and specially some answers, might be useful for someone. Therefore I'll let this question unmodified and I'll try to reformulate the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23809810/1659599).

---

Overriding the template `folder_full_view_item.pt` with `z3c.jbot` will override the template for all Content Types.
How do I override it only for a single Content Type `MyType` in a Product with many types?

Having the following structure:

```
Folder (layout=folder_full_view)
    Document (layout=document_view)
    MyType (layout=mytype_view)
```

The default steps in Plone are:

1. The template `folder_full_view.pt` calls `folder_full_view_item.pt` via `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()`.
2. Products.CMFPlone's template `folder_full_view_item.pt` adds different ViewletManagers (abovecontenttitle etc.) and calls the item's layout via `use-macro="item_macro"`.
3. The template of the item (`document_view`, `mytype_view` etc.) is included.

What I need is a way to override the template `folder_full_view_item.pt`. Calling in step #2 the overridden template `folder_full_view_item.pt` for `MyType` and Plone's `folder_full_view_item.pt` for all other Content Types.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the template `folder_full_view_item.pt` cannot be overriden (without using jbot). The call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` in the template `folder_full_view.pt` doesn't seems to go through "queryMultiAdapter" neither.

I present here all the steps to reproduce it and confirm that `folder_full_view_item` is ignored:

Set the `PLONE_HOME` path and remove existing `exaple.theme` if necessary:

```sh
PLONE_HOME=/path/to/Plone-4.3.2
cd ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src
rm -rf ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme
sed -i '/example\.theme/d' ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/buildout.cfg
```

run buildout with `develop.cfg`:

```sh
sudo -u plone_buildout ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/bin/buildout -c ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/develop.cfg
cd ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src
rm -rf /home/Plone-4.3.2/zeocluster/src/example.theme
sudo -u plone_buildout ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/bin/paster create \
        --no-interactive \
        --overwrite \
        -o ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src \
        -t plone3_theme example.theme \
        expert_mode=all \
        namespace_package=example \
        package=theme \
        skinname='ExampleTheme' \
        skinbase='Sunburst Theme' \
        empty_styles=False \
        include_doc=True \
        version=1.0 \
        description='An installable theme for Plone 3' \
        add_profile=True \
        long_description= \
        author= \
        author_email= \
        keywords='web zope plone theme' \
        url='http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/' \
        license_name=GPL \
        zip_safe=False \
        zope2product=True
```

add `example.theme` to buildout:

```
sed -i '79i\ \ \ \ example.theme' ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/buildout.cfg
sed -i '102i\ \ \ \ src/example.theme' ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/buildout.cfg
```

register `browser:pages`

```xml
cat << EOF > ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/configure.zcml
<configure
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:cmf="http://namespaces.zope.org/cmf"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    i18n_domain="example.theme">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />
  <include package=".browser" />
  <include file="skins.zcml" />
  <include file="profiles.zcml" />
  <i18n:registerTranslations directory="locales" />

  <browser:page
     for="*"
     name="folder_full_view_item"
     template="folder_full_view_item.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />

  <browser:page
     for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.folder.ATFolder"
     name="folder_full_view"
     template="folder_full_view.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />

  <browser:page
     for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.document.ATDocument"
     name="document_view"
     template="document_view.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />

</configure>
EOF
```

copy original files (`document_view.pt`, `folder_full_view.pt`, and `folder_full_view_item.pt`) to theme:

```sh
cp -f ${PLONE_HOME}/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/document_view.pt \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/document_view.pt
cp -f ${PLONE_HOME}/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/folder_full_view_item.pt \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view_item.pt
cp -f ${PLONE_HOME}/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/folder_full_view.pt \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view.pt
```

slightly modify overriden templates to recognize them:

```sh
sed -i '/<metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">/a overriden template at '${PLONE_HOME}'/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/document_view.pt' \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/document_view.pt
sed -i '/<metal:entries fill-slot="entries">/a overriden template at '${PLONE_HOME}'/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view.pt' \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view.pt
sed -i '/<div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontenttitle" \/>/i overriden template at '${PLONE_HOME}'/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view_item.pt' \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/folder_full_view_item.pt
chown -R plone_buildout example.theme
```

run buildout and start plone:

```sh
sudo -u plone_buildout ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/bin/buildout -c ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/develop.cfg
${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/bin/zeoserver restart
${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/bin/client1 fg
```

If you want to programmatically create test data (e.g. from ipython) then you could do the following:

```py
utils.sync()
plone_site_name = 'Plone'
# delete 'Plone' site if existing
if app.hasObject(plone_site_name): app.manage_delObjects(plone_site_name)
from Products.CMFPlone.factory import addPloneSite
# create 'Plone' site
plone_site = addPloneSite(
                        app,
                        plone_site_name,
                        profile_id=('Products.CMFPlone:plone',),
                        extension_ids=('plonetheme.classic:default',
                                        'plonetheme.sunburst:default',),
                        setup_content=False,
                    )
plone_site = app[plone_site_name]
# install 'plone.app.theming' and 'example.theme'
plone_site.portal_quickinstaller.installProduct('plone.app.theming')
plone_site.portal_quickinstaller.installProduct('example.theme')
# create some content
plone_site.invokeFactory('Document', 'document')
folder_id = plone_site.invokeFactory('Folder', 'folder')
plone_site[folder_id].setLayout('folder_full_view')
plone_site[folder_id].invokeFactory('Document', 'document')
utils.commit()
```

**UPDATE 2**

Adding the following as suggested doesn't work either:

define a subclass from zope.interface.Interface:

```py
cat << EOF >> ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/browser/interfaces.py
from zope.interface import Interface
class IMyLayer(Interface):
    """ """
EOF
```

register it as a browser layer:

```py
cat << EOF > ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/profiles/default/browserlayer.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layers>
  <layer name="imylayer" interface="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IMyLayer" />
</layers>
EOF
```

register the browser:page for this layer:

```xml
sed -i 's/layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"/layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IMyLayer"/' \
    ${PLONE_HOME}/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/configure.zcml
```

**UPDATE 3**

The call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` seems not to go through the "usual" layers!

I've tested the following with the example above:

in `folder_full_view` substitute the call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` with `item.getObject().document_view()`

modify the original `document_view.pt`

```
echo "original document_view" > ${PLONE_HOME}/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/document_view.pt
```

modify the `document_view.pt` in `example.theme`

```
echo "overriden document_view" > /home/Plone-4.3.2/zeocluster/src/example.theme/example/theme/document_view.pt
```

calling the document uses the overriden `document_view.pt`

```
curl -s 'http://localhost:8080/Plone/document' | grep "document_view"
overriden document_view
```

but calling the folder (with a document in it) uses the original `document_view.pt`

```
curl -s 'http://localhost:8080/Plone/folder' | grep "document_view"
original document_view
```

Thus the central questions seem to be:

goes the call `item.getObject().template_name()` in a template through the "usual" publishing/layers process?

If not, how to call a template like `folder_full_view_item` form `folder_full_view` and make it go trough the "usual" publishing/layers process?

Can someone give a hint for which part of zope/plone is responsible for this "publishing/layers process"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding `folder_full_view_item.pt` you should rather [create your own custom default template](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-a-custom-template-for-a-plone-content-type) for your Content Type `MyType`.

Comment: actually what I need is to override folder_full_view_item. I want MyType show with its own view/template in the enclosing folder which has the layout folder_full_view selected. The folder_full_view of the enclosing folder calls "item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()" which in turn calls the template of MyType. folder_full_view_item not only calls MyType's template but it adds some additional elements that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

To override this template you will need 2 things: a browser layer and the view that is going to be used in the context of your content type.

First, declare the browser layer:

```py
from zope.interface import Interface

class IMyLayer(Interface):
    """A layer specific for this add-on product.
    """
```

This browser layer needs to be installed with your content type. Create a **browserlayer.xml** file with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layers>
  <layer name="my.type" interface="my.type.interfaces.IMyLayer" />
</layers>
```

Then, the view will be active when you are in the context of your content type and when your browser layer is active:

```py
from five import grok

class FolderFullViewItem(grok.View):
    """Override folder_full_view_item for MyType.
    """
    grok.context(IMyType)
    grok.layer(IMyLayer)
    grok.name('folder_full_view_item')
    grok.template('folder_full_view_item')
    grok.require('zope2.View')
```

On [sc.blog](https://github.com/simplesconsultoria/sc.blog) we have a similar use case on which we override **folder_summary_view** and **folder_full_view**, take a look on it.

Also, don't forget to read the [Layers](http://developer.plone.org/views/layers.html) chapter on the Plone Developers Documentation.

Comment: I do exactly want to **override** `folder_full_view_item.pt`, not `folder_full_view.pt`. In your mentioned example `sc.blog` you just override `folder_full_view.pt` which calls Plone's `folder_full_view_item.pt`. I do know that I could overwrite `folder_full_view.pt` for `MyType` and there call another template instead of `folder_full_view_item.pt` but this is not what I am asking. Please read carefully my question.

Comment: if you read carefully my answer you will notice that `grok.context(IMyType)` does the work.

Comment: would you mind to ungrok your answer? Our project is grokless

Comment: It seems that the `template folder_full_view_item.pt` cannot be overriden (without using jbot!). The call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` in the template `folder_full_view.pt` not even seems to be the case that it goes through "queryMultiAdapter". See my question update.

Comment: Hector, your answer applies for all other templates to be overriden. But unfortunately it doesn't apply for the template `folder_full_view_item.pt`. Or did I misunderstand the whole layers issue?

Comment: don't use an IThemeSpecific layer, but a simple marker interface.

Comment: could you please offer a specific line of code? I've spent hours reading cryptic hints and followed broken links on Plone docs. I also read carefully your answer above and studied your code on sc.blog. Obvioulsy without any success. What is it that I do not understand? I'd very much apreciate it if you could give me a clear answer that works with the example offered in my question above.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you right now; I'm very busy.

Comment: I've used (what I understand as) a simple marker interface. See above. Unfortunately it doesn't work either. See my update 2

Comment: Either I don't understand it at all or the call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` definitely does not search the layers as usual and thus it cannot be overriden. See my update 3

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tal:condition="python:item_type=='MyType'"` and `item_type!='MyType'` for different display needs. Hope this helpful.

Comment: I do exactly want to **override** `folder_full_view_item.pt`. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As the skins-tool seems to be deprecated and probably performance-losses would be involved,  I'd rather go with a dedicated browser-view for your custom-contenttype, too, but to answer the question:

You can use [collective.editskinswitcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.editskinswitcher) (thanks to M. v. Rees!), without rewriting too much and even getting some nice and easy to configure dev-features along the way (visitors-view, while actually logged-in, via URL-distinction, e.g.).

In this case, we take advantage of the possibility to set the skin-property on a folderish contenttype-object and roughly, these steps should make the deal:

- Place the customized `folder_full_view_item.pt` -template in any of your theme's skin-folders.
- On creation of your contenttype, add an event-listener, which sets the freshly born object's `skin_name` to your theme's skin-name (have a look at c.editskinswitcher for methods and props, the referring HTTP-request is `@@switchDefaultSkin?skin_name=YourTheme`, btw).
- Set another theme-skin as the global default for all other contextes in portal_skins-properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is exactly what we are using now: a combination of themes/skins which we switch with `collective.editskinswitcher`. Indeed, thanks to Maurits! But, aside that this juggling and fighting with the libraries (and the documentation!) sometimes becomes a real pita, I am actually and really very interested in an answer to my questions: (1) is it or is it not possible to override `folder_full_view_item.pt` as most people (precipitately) suggest? and (2) is there another way to call this template than via `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()`?

Comment: On the other side I would very much appreciate a clear statement from the plone developers on what libs/tools are "deprecated", "old-fashioned", "old-style" etc. etc.? But this forum is really not the place to complain about this ;-) Even if I appreciate very much your effort @ida-ebkes, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The quest has grown into a novel (aka tl;dr) and rises several points, by now. Concerning (1) of your comment: That has been answered in many ways by now, feel free to show your appreciation with upvotes (I did). Concerning (2): There is always a way ;) But maybe you want to open a new quest with this specific point. About the rants in the second comment: Skins-tool is definitely ment to be deprecated but there has some stuff to be done before time has come finally for the good-bye. It should probably be better documented and discussed, as you suggest, which rises the next quest:

Comment: Where to discuss? Traditionally that happens on the mailing-lists, then SO was included as support-option and now we have community.plone.org but no official switch, yet. So, I re-asked here: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/moving-to-community-plone-org-td7571074.html#a7571499 about the current communication-channels-state.

Comment: To summarize this quest: No, you cannot make a skin-template behave exactly like a browser-view, obviously. However your usecase can be solved in various much better ways.

Comment: Unfortunately my question is still not answered. Even if there are lots of workarounds, what I just want to know is jsut (1) why `folder_full_view_item.pt` cannot(!) be overriden and `folder_full_view.pt` can(!) be overriden? and (2) is there a way to substitute the call `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` by something else calling `folder_full_view_item.pt` forcing it to go through the publishing process?

Comment: You keep repeating `folder_full_view_item.pt` cannot be overriden, which is not true. The additional request was to do it only for a contype: has been answered and was a funny challenge in conjunction with an "oldskool"-template, btw, thx. A complete other quest, is the usecase to distinct which view/template of an item is to be shown inside of `folder_full_view.pt`, which is the concerned template to be customized, actually. Of there distinct with tal-conditions and point to the desired special view/template (see marr's answer). That's how I'd do it at least.

Comment: Please read carefully my example (I've offered all the code!) and please be so kind to falsify the statement that "folder_full_view_item.pt" cannot be overriden in the same way as "folder_full_view.pt" (see configure.zcml). I'd very much appreciate you showing where I'm wrong. I guess I am. But I really cannot see where or how. Please offer a demonstration with reproducible code and do not simply state "is not true". I've offered all the steps to reproduce my example. It is really not intended to be a "novel".

Comment: E.g., your quest starts with "Overriding the template folder_full_view_item.pt with z3c.jbot will override the template for all Content Types" where you confirm that you have overriden it, already. Later on you state you don't want to use jbot, which changes the quest, and so on, that's what I ment with "novel", it's many questions in one and hard to follow and honestly I didn't read it all, beside of the odd approach, denying to customize `folder_full_view.pt` instead of `folder_full_view_item.pt` and provide a dedicated template, for which the actual requirement is screaming for.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This question has grown to a kind of monster. I've reformulate this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23809810/1659599. I hope that the new question is clearer. @IdaEbkes: Thanks for your suggestions.