# How to override template “folder_full_view_item.pt”?

Tags: plone, theming

This question is a reformulation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21464202/1659599) which had evolved in a confusing way. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21464202/1659599) if you search some in depth details or are interested in workarounds and alternative solutions.

This question is about the call to template `folder_full_view_item.pt` in `folder_full_view.pt`, not about other templates in general!

Please avoid workarounds like skin layers, editskinswitcher, etc. I don't want to solve a particular use case here. What I want is to really understand how this actually works.

I present this question in three parts: scenario, result, questions.

### scenario

Have a Folder with a Document. The layout of the Folder is `folder_full_view`. The layout of the Document is `document_view`:

```
Folder (layout=folder_full_view)
    Document (layout=document_view)
```

The template `folder_full_view.pt` calls template `folder_full_view_item.pt` via `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()`.
`folder_full_view_item.pt` calls (e.g. for a Document content type ) the template `document_view.pt` via `use-macro="item_macro"` (`item_macro` being something like `here/document_view/macros/content-core`). Schematically as follows:

```
folder_full_view.pt :: item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()
    folder_full_view_item.pt :: use-macro="here/document_view/macros/content-core"
        document_view.pt
```

In a `plone3_theme` have overriden versions of the templates `folder_full_view.pt`, `folder_full_view_item.pt`, and `document_view.pt`. These templates are registered as follows in `configure.zcml`.

```xml
  <browser:page
     for="*"
     name="folder_full_view_item"
     template="folder_full_view_item.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />

  <browser:page
     for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.folder.ATFolder"
     name="folder_full_view"
     template="folder_full_view.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />

  <browser:page
     for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.document.ATDocument"
     name="document_view"
     template="document_view.pt"
     layer="example.theme.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     permission="zope2.View"
     />
```

### results

With the theme installed the results are:

Document and Folder get their templates (I guess) via traversal. The (sub)templates though don't go through the traversal.

Folder: uses **overriden** `folder_full_view.pt`, **original** `folder_full_view_item.pt`, and **original** `document_view.pt`

[image]

Document: uses **overriden** `document_view.pt`

[image]

### questions

1. is it the case that `item.getObject().folder_full_view_item()` doesn't go through traversal? If yes why?
2. what can be modified (in `folder_full_view.pt`!) to force a traversal to the overriden `folder_full_view_item.pt`(!) and subsequently to the overriden `document_view.pt`? Is this possible?

Again, please avoid workarounds like skin layers, editskinswitcher, etc. I don't want to solve a particular use case here. What I want is to really understand how this actually works.